# DynamicDictionary is gone on ElasticSearch 2.0 (Elasticsearch.Net)

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, elasticsearch, nest, nest2

In my previous code I was using a `DynamicDictionary` as a base class for my `DataRecordDictionary` document

```
[ElasticsearchType(Name = "DataRecordDictionary")]
public class DataRecordDictionary : DynamicDictionary
{
    [String(Store = false, Index = FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed)]
    public string FileId { get; set; }

    [Date(Store = false)]
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
}
```

So I was able to store the `FileId`, the `Timestamp` and a custom set of key-value pairs (note the base class)

Now, having updated to NEST2 and ElasticSearch2 the `DynamicDictionary` is gone but I still need to persist key-value pairs on the database.

Is there any new dictionary data structure I could use which is recognized by Elasticsearch and that can be stored in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DynamicDictionary is renamed to `DynamicResponse`. See the [release notes](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/master/docs/2.0-breaking-changes/elasticsearch-net-breaking-changes.md#renamed-types) of ES for breaking changes in v2.0 release.